# Xamarin.forms iOS crashes on AppCenter.Start in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-2022

I installed latest version of Visual Studio 2022 (17.0.2).
Created a brand new Xamarin.Forms project.
Wanted to test AppCenter Analytics and Crashes.

Added following line of code in OnStart event of App.Xaml.cs

```
AppCenter.Start("android={android key};" +
                  "ios={iOS key}",
                  typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
```

Installed Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics and Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes nuget packages in all three (shared, android, iOS) projects.

Works fine in Android..

Crashes on this line in iOS. I am trying to debug in iPhone physical device using hot restart. When I remove the above line it works just fine.

I tried this on multiple computers but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: This issue has been reported here : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12918 , due to the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#limitations) of hot restart , I would suggest you try the same code without hot restart (build with a mac).

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT I see that issue is closed by the poster saying "no longer an issue"
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12918#issuecomment-953948275

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: I wrapped this code in a try catch block but the exception is coming as null. So I don't know what the error is.

Comment: Here 18 months later, using latest xamarin forms, vs2022 and appcenter, I have the exact same issue with the null exception on start for iOS. Any news on this?